# Changing nested Mysqli queries to JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

We're updated the below legacy PHP, and I'd like to convert the nested loop into a `JOIN` query instead due to issues with the nested query not outputting content.

It's important to output `<optgroup>` elements for each category group (depicted in the database by `parentCategory_id=0`) with nested `<option>` tags for each category. See below desired HTML output.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

**PHP**

```
<select name="category">
  <option value="">All categories</option>

  <?php
    // Get category groups
    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentCategory_id=0 ORDER BY category_id");
    while ($parent = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>

      <optgroup label='<?=$parent["cat_name"];?>'>

        <?php
        // Find all child categories
        $catQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentCategory_id=$parent[category_id]");
        while ($category = $catQ->fetch_assoc($catQ)) {
        ?>

          <option value='<?=$category["category_id"];?>' $selected><?=$category["cat_name"];?></option>

        <?php } ?>

      </optgroup>

    <?php }
      $q->close();
    ?>
</select>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="category">
  <option value="">All categories</option>

  <optgroup label="Clothing">
    <option value="1">Mens</option>
    <option value="2">Womens</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Jewellery">
    <option value="3">Gold</option>
    <option value="4">Silver</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: What is the generated html you get in the browser?

Comment: @Kypros have added desired HTML output to the question.

Comment: @NickPrice `parentCategory_id=0` why ??

Comment: @meda To determine which categories are to be outputted as groups. It's legacy code; we'd rather not amend the database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it is legacy code, but the issue here is logic

Just look at the queries your self.

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentCategory_id=0 ORDER BY category_id
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parentCategory_id=$parent[category_id]
```

It is the same table, why query the same table?

How do you expect to do a JOIN ? on itself ?

---

`JOIN` is for at least 2 tables, what you need to do is restructure your data in PHP:

```
$categories = array();
while ($cat = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[$cat['cat_name']][$cat['category_id']] = $cat['cat_type'];
}
```

then build your select:

```
<select name="category">
  <option value="">All categories</option>
<?php foreach($categories as $label => $opt): ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($opt as $id => $name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is what I'm stumped by. Is there no way to `group` on the the parent, and output the children beneath it?

Comment: @NickPrice what does the first select give you

Comment: Would give the parent categories; ready to loop through the children by matching `category_id` to the childrens' `parentCategory_id`. However, in the current code the nested query does not actually do anything (there is no result, looks like it doesn't execute).

Comment: but if `categories` is the parent table, what is the child one

Comment: They're in the same table. Hence the problem! Heavily considering changing the database structure - but that really is a last resort.

Comment: @NickPrice ok I understand now, where do you get the value `Clothing` in  `<optgroup label="Clothing">`

Comment: Welcome, I also cleared the downvote on your post as I dont see anything wrong woth it